# PHP: params must be mixed

Tags: php

It seems the whole world community has never encountered this php error before, judging from google results:

I am trying to set up the Typo3 CMS and I get this error

`Type of TYPO3\CMS\Core\IO\CsvStreamFilter::$params must be mixed (as in class php_user_filter) in C:\xampp\htdocs\typo3test\example-project-directory\public\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\IO\CsvStreamFilter.php on line 26`

Line 26 in that file looks as follows:

`class CsvStreamFilter extends \php_user_filter`

I am rather new to PHP, how do I fix this error?
What I have tried so far:

- changing`declare(strict_types=1)` in that file to `declare(strict_types=0)` but it just gets overwritten again

Help!

Comment: submit an issue (and preferably a PR) in typo3

Comment: well it [was done already a year ago](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/commit/cd399d1a4f5307bac4104440cc8f300af231e164). Just update your outdated codebase

Comment: Thank you, my Common Sense, always great when you come back. @YourCommonSense Indeed the typo instructions I copied were outdated and used version `11` which I just had to replace by `11.5.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions in the typo3 guide are slightly outdated.

So in `composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution:^11 example-project-directory` just replace `11` with `11.5.1` or whatever is the lastest version.